# API para obtener realizar búsqueda por nombre de ciudad y obtener su estado/comunidad, país y continente

Tags: api, localización

estoy buscando una API que permita obtener lo que expongo y aunque mi primer referente a sido el servicio de autocomplete de Google Place API Web Services no he conseguido de una forma clara obtener lo que quiero. ¿Alguna recomendación? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Probaste con http://www.geonames.org/? Tiene una API que te puede ser de utilidad: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html